# Динамический combo webix

Tags: json, webix, combo

В `webix` есть комбо панель туда передаю `json`:

```
view: "combo",
 label: "Выберите систему",
 width: 150,
 required: true,
 invalidMessage: "Заполните",
 id: "systemId",
 name: "systemId",
 yCount: "2",
 value: 'name',
 options: "/adminstrator/ws/person/systemCombo"
```

`json` приходит в таком виде:

```
[{"hSystemId":1,"name":"CBD"},{"hSystemId":2,"name":"EAPP"}]
```

но `name` не могу вывести вместо `displayValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы передаете в json и ID и name, то в value необходимо указывать именно ID, а не name, по аналогии с компонентом select.

Пример: http://webix.com/snippet/3b01f90b